# For the given combination in a data frame, calculate the frequency of occurrence of that combination in another data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, frequency

I am having a data frame that has various combinations as follows:

```
    structure(list(`Q1` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Q2` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Q3` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0), `Q4` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Q5` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), `Q6` = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), `Q7` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Q8` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1), `Q9` = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), `Q10` = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Q11` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `Q12` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am having a base data frame where I have different combinations with the weightage for each combination.

```
structure(list(Q1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), Q2 = c(0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q3 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), Q4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q5 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), Q6 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), Q7 = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q8 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0), Q9 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), Q10 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q11 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q12 = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), RatingBinary = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The problem statement is for each 1's combination in 1st data frame (i.e.Q6, Q9, Q12 in 1st row, Q3, Q6, Q12 in 2nd row), I need to get the number of rows that get satisfied in the base data frame.

*For example: In the combination data frame (1st Df), in the 1st row Q6, Q9 & Q12 have the binary value `1`. I need to get the count of this combination(Q6, Q9 & Q12 which have 1's) in the base data and get the number of rows that have the `RatingBinary` values 0's and 1's.*

How can I get this implemented in R? Can anyone suggest a suitable solution for this scenario?

Comment: Have you tried something? What is your expected output for the given data?

Comment: By "count of this combination...in the base data", do you mean you want to find all instances in the base data where Q6, Q9, and Q12 equal 1, and then where Q3, Q6, Q12 equal 1, and so forth. Then, by "get the number of rows...", do you want to summarize how many rows have RatingBinary = 0 and how many rows have 1 for each set (define set as 1) Q6, Q9, Q12; 2) Q3, Q6, Q12, etc.)?

Comment: @latlio - Yeah exactly!

Comment: @Ronak Shah - Can you please have a look at latlio comment? That's the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an algorithmic approach.

Let's call a set in the first data frame a combo set; this is a set of three questions in a given row. Let's also call a set in the base data a base set; this is the set in a given row for which we are trying to find whether a given combo set is part of.

The approach is essentially to iterate through each combo set and find matches over all base sets. Sets seem to only be in threes, so I take advantage of that by hard coding a `sum == 3` rather than doing an agnostic match. We store matches in a structure I call `pair`. A match is indicated by a `1`. I define pair(x,y) where x is the row number of the combo data set and y is the row number of base dataset.

```
pair <- matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  ind <- which(df[i,] == 1)
  for(j in 1:nrow(df2)) {
    if(sum(df2[j, ind]) == 3){
      pair[i,j] <- 1
    } else {
      pair[i,j] <- 0
    }
  }
}
```

The pair object is:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

This means for only the first combo set did we find matches in all the base sets except for base set 4 and base set 5. Because there is only one match, the answer to your second question about the number of rows that have `RatingBinary` 0 or 1 becomes trivial -- it's just the `RatingBinary` for that row/base set in the base data set.